# Windows XP stuck in loop

Tags: windows, multi-boot

I've an old PC, which was used in dual-Boot with Linux Mint. I removed the Linux Mint partitions and an old data partition and enlarged the Windows XP partition. After starting, I got the `grub not there` (or the like) message.

Then I tried to started from the Windows XP install-CD to use the rescue mode to fix the MBR, but it crashes (something with `PCI.SYS`). I tried `testdisk` and it started to boot. I was relieved, but then.. it just restarted.

I've no idea what to do, to get this machine working again. If you need any information leave a comment.

Comment: At which point exactly does the crash occur? If you cannot boot from the XP CD at all, [restoring](http://robert.penz.name/221/mini-howto-restore-windows-mbrbootloader-with-linux/) or [clearing](http://blog.onetechnical.com/2007/07/10/clearing-out-the-master-boot-record-with-linux/) the MBR using a Linux LiveCD should help (the XP CD should boot after that), but be *extremely* careful with *dd* and the like and don't specify the wrong device by mistake!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should reinstall your entire operating system as it might not be repairable with the Windows XP disk anymore.

Just use the disk to reinstall the OS.

Comment: Especially if it's an old system- it's likely a clean install will improve performance quite significantly.

Comment: The problem is that the CD crashes with a bluescreen and some address after 'PCI.SYS' (something like this: http://forum.novatech.co.uk/files/pci-sys.gif) so I might not even be able to re-install it.

Comment: Why not install a different OS. Like Linux(Ubuntu). Just get on a working computer and download it.

Answer (score 0):

Re-installing Windows from scratch will be the most sure-fire way of restoring your Windows bootloader. However if you want to try recovering your system, follow these instructions from [http://linux.koolsolutions.com](http://linux.koolsolutions.com/2009/06/08/howto-how-to-erase-un-install-grub-from-mbr-to-restore-windowsdos-bootloader/).

> **Method 2: Use a Windows XP installation CD/DVD**
>
> Grab a Windows XP installation CD and boot from the CD with the hard
>   drive attached and select the “Repair” (choose “R”) option when it is
>   presented to you. After that you will taken a common prompt. Once you
>   get to the command prompt give the following command after selecting
>   “1″ for :
>
> 1) C:\WINDOWS and now type the following commands:

```
C:\WINDOWS> CD .. 
C:\> FIXBOOT C: 
C:\> FIXMBR 
C:\> BOOTCFG /rebuild
```

> The last command (BOOTCFG) will rebuild your boot.ini as per your hard
>   drive partition table and will put appropriate entries for Windows XP.
>   Also this command will most likley add a new entry to your Windows XP
>   boot menu. You can easily delete the old entry by modifying the
>   C:\boot.ini file once you successfully boot into Windows using the
>   newly created entry.
>
> **Note:** You will need to know the “Administrator” password before you
>   can enter into the command prompt. If you don’t have one, just press
>   “Enter” key.

Comment: The problem is that the CD crashes with a bluescreen and some address after 'PCI.SYS' (something like this: http://forum.novatech.co.uk/files/pci-sys.gif)